# Navigation with logo in the centre and two links on each side

Tags: html, css, flexbox, justify

I'm trying to create a navigation with a logo in the centre and two links on each side. I want the links which are on the side to be closer to the logo than the borders of the page. I think I might be able to do this using position, top, left property and etc but then the website becomes a mess when I make it a lower resolution. That's why I'm trying to utilise flexbox which I saw a couple of days ago in a video about html on YouTube.

Thank you for the help!

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.photoauraone {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    size: cover;
}


.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 5%;
    width: 5%;
}

.backgroundimage {
    background-image: url("photoauraone.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}



header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
    order: -1;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RADIO AURA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="backgroundimage">
        <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="wrapper">
                <ul class="left_links">    
                    <il><a href="">About Us</a></il>
                    <il><a href="">Shows</a></il>
                
                    <il><a href=""><img src="logo_normal_purple.png" class="logo"></a></il>
                    
                    <il><a href="">Player</a></il>
                    <il><a href="">Contacts</a></il>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </header>  
    </div>  


    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most responsive solution is probably to use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).
In example I've used `display:flex`, [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`align-items: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

I provide a clean solution to make it clear what I did.

```css
nav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50"/>
  <div>
    <a href="#">link 3</a>
    <a href="#">link 4</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

For each attribute I used, I provided a link to guide. I hope this helps you in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it and it really looks something similar to what I had in mind. Although when I put it in my page - everything goes to the left. Here I attach an image - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hk53ASwwVDli_5bMjCgs2Em6dZejJt0z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also from what I see when I run the code snippet , the links are nearer to the borders of the page and not the logo. That's one thing I try to fix. If I find a website with a similar nav bar with what I have in mind I'm going to link it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>RADIO AURA</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_index.css">
  
<style>
    .container {width: 100%; max-width: 800px;}
nav {
    width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="backgroundimage">
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
              <div> <a href="#">link 1</a> <a href="#">link 2</a> </div>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50"/>
              <div> <a href="#">link 3</a> <a href="#">link 4</a> </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```